# Using jQuery and JavaScript to sum the asp text box value in the repeater control and show the result in the result asp label?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-events

I am using jQuery and JavaScript to sum  the asp text box value in the repeater control and show the result in the result asp label. I want to know how to set the value in asp label in jQuery. Here I got the error:

> The name 'lblTotal' does not exist in the current context...

```
if (objIndex == 0) {
                    objData = new Array();
                }
                objData[objIndex] = txtBoxValue;
                alert(secName);
                totamt = 120000;
                var Tot = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < objData.length; i++) {
                    Tot = parseInt(Tot) + parseInt(objData[i]);
                }

                if (parseInt(Tot) > parseInt(totamt)) {
                        var a = $("#<%= lblTotal.ClientID%>").val('totamt');
                    alert(a);

                }
                else if (parseInt(Tot) <= parseInt(totamt)) {
                var b = $("#<%= lblTotal.ClientID%>").val('Tot');
                    alert(b);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `label` is inside the `Repeater` so its not visible directly therefore you can't use

```
<%= lblTotal.ClientID%>
```

You should find that control like

```
    var controls = yourParentControl.getElementsByTagName("SPAN");
//this will give you array of controls after that you should iterate in that 
//collection and find out the label you want to set total to.
```

SPAN because `labels` rendered as `SPANs`

Comment: hi i am using repeater control inside the repeater control.In Child repeater  i am adding the text box value and show the result in the parent repeater control label.here i got the sum value in child repeater but i want to identify the label in child repeater so please help me how to get the parent control.. give some sample code ....

Comment: @saravananraj Without looking at the markup its not possible to provide any solution, you should post a question with this comment more elaborated and with some code to get the idea.

Comment: hi sir i post this coding clearly in stack over flow. or type this question in google  it will be there.how to sum the text box value in child repeater control and show the result in parent repeater label using java script and jquery?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using client-side (JQuery code) you should give your labels a class you can use to easily select them. E.g. from your repeater template:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    ...
    <asp:Label runat='server' Text='' CssClass='class1 class2 totalable' />
    ...
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then in your client-side code, *after* the repeater has rendered you can loop through all the labels that have the `totalable` class and do the adding.

So at the point you want to total up the values:

```
var total = 0;


$('.totalable').each(function () {
    //alert($(this).html());
    total+=  parseInt($(this).html());
    ....
});

alert('Total = ' + total);
```

Comment: i am getting error like Total=NaN...       
                    var total = 0;


                    $('.Totalable').each(function() {
                    //alert($(this).html());
                    //total = total + parseFloat($(this).val());
                    total+=  parseFloat($(this).html());
                    });

                    alert('Total = ' + total);

Comment: Maybe check you are using the same class name (check the casing is the same too) in your Label's `CssClass` attribute and in your javascript.

 And check the HTML source to make sure all the labels contain numeric characters only.

Comment: all should same but i am using this control in repeater.

Comment: *Should* ?  Do a 'View Source ...' and check it to make sure values are being added to the spans. Paste your markup here if you want us to take a look at it.

Comment: s.. it should be span only...and this the code...  here .Totalable is the cssclass name of the text box. var total = 0; $('.Totalable').each(function() { total+= parseFloat($(this).html()); }); alert('Total = ' + total);

Comment: I meant the source of your HTML - do a view source ... in your webbrowser and check the markup. 

Also try inserting an `alert($(this).html());` in the `each`block to ensure all your SPANs have numbers in them.